# Oracle ADF: SkinFactory is not working correctely in JDeveloper 12.1.3

Tags: java, jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, trinidad

I use the code below to populate my skin list and give the user the possibility the change the skin at runtime.

```
public List getSkinChoices() {
    List choices = new ArrayList();
    String skinFamily = null;
    String skinLabel = null;
    SkinFactory sf = SkinFactory.getFactory();
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    for (Iterator i = sf.getSkinIds(); i.hasNext();) {
        String skinID = (String) i.next();
        Skin skin = sf.getSkin(context, skinID);
        skinFamily = skin.getFamily();
        skinLabel = skinFamily;
        if (skin.getRenderKitId().indexOf("desktop") > 0 ) {
            choices.add(new SelectItem(skinFamily, skinLabel));
        }
    }
    return choices;
}
```

Now that i am using Jdev 12.1.3 the method `sf.getSkinIds();` is deprecated.
The method is no more loading all skin as usually 
[image]

Could somebody directes me to the new implementation way?
Is there any alternativ to get all availlable skins?

NB: The code about loads all availlable skin in Jdev 12.1.2.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SkinFactory` class is part of the Trinidad API and according to its [javadoc](http://javadox.com/org.apache.myfaces.trinidad/trinidad-api/2.1.0/org/apache/myfaces/trinidad/skin/SkinFactory.html#getSkinIds()), you have to:

> Use [`SkinProvider#getSkinMetadata()`](http://javadox.com/org.apache.myfaces.trinidad/trinidad-api/2.1.0/org/apache/myfaces/trinidad/skin/SkinProvider.html#getSkinMetadata(javax.faces.context.FacesContext)) to get the list of skins supported.

So, you have to do something like this:

```
Collection<SkinMetadata> supportedSkins = SkinProvider.getSkinMetadata(context);
Iterator<SkinMetadata> iterator = supportedSkins.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    SkinMetadata next = iterator.next();
    skinFamily = next.getFamily();
    //etc.
}
```